# How can I further customize my legend while using ggsurvplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival-analysis

The default settings show lines in the legend, but to make it easier to read, I would prefer to show squares or circles. My current legend looks like this:

[image: current legend]

I would like it to look more like this:

[image]

I think I need to add this to my script somehow, but I can't use "+" with ggsurvplot like I can with ggplot.

`guides(alpha = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 16) ) )`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one potential solution:

```r
library(survival)
library(survminer)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survminer'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:survival':
#> 
#>     myeloma

fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot1 <- ggsurvplot(fit, data = lung)$plot

ggplot1 +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 16,
                                                  linetype = c(NA, NA))))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>